# How can I count lines with title-case words of certain length?

Tags: text-processing

How can I create a shell script in unix/linux to find the number of lines in a text file that have words which are 5 to 10 character long and begin with a capital letter?

Comment: I've heavily edited this question, please ensure it still conveys your original question.

Comment: Steven D.. that was a hard call :)  it was difficult to know if dimpal meant "number of lines" or "line numbers"... I guess he'll pipe up one way or the other...

Comment: @fred.bear: Indeed.  Not sure which he meant so I allowed the given answer to guide me a bit.

Comment: I added an alternate solution in case he meant he wanted the line numbers that match. I think that should cover it.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the original question meant to *count* the number of lines matching the above requirements, then this should do it:

```
grep -e '\<[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]\{4,9\}\>' file|wc -l
```

Assuming it meant to *print* the line numbers that match:

```
awk --re-interval '{line = line + 1} /\<[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]{4,9}\>/ {print line}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "^[A-Z]" FILE | egrep -c "\b[A-Za-z]{5,10}\b"
```

The way the question is now, it means, filter out lines, starting with a capital letter (like this line) [the line has to start with a capital letter - not the word], and include a word (not necessarily the first word) which is 5 to 10 characters long.

Yes, after reading the original question, there are 4 possibilities to interpret it: The Starting word has to fulfill both requirements or it is a starting word and another word, and: Get the line numbers, or the number of lines.

To print the line numbers for lines, which begin with a capital letter, and contain a word somewhere of length 5-10, we use sed:

```
sed -nr '/^[A-Z][a-z]{4,9}/=;/^[A-Z].*\b[A-Za-z]{5,10}\b/=' FILE
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without some more info from the original poster, but I believe that is what @dimpal intended in the original question -- to count the number of lines that had at least one word between 5 and 10 characters long that starts with a capital letter. Also the solution you posted would match the line "F foobar", for example.

Comment: Yes, intentionally my first solution does. The line starts with a capital letter and contains a word of length 5-10. Think either: `find the number of (lines in a text file that (have words which are 5 to 10 character long) and (begin with a capital letter))` OR `find the number of lines in a text file that have (words (which are 5 to 10 character long) and (begin with a capital letter))`.

Comment: The original question was "a shell script in unix/linux to find the lines number of a text file are having words which are 5 to 10 character long and having first letter as a capital letter", again, it's ambiguous but it sounds like he meant words that start with a capital letter, not lines that start with a capital letter.

Comment: Well, tak, I didn't vote you down or suggested your answer is wrong, but said, that I see 4 possibilities, and I provided what I think is  a solution to 2 interpretations, which were not addressed by your solutions - no? Your interpretation might be better, but now I stop to argue, and work on an correction for my answers, which is needed. But I can vote your answer up, if it succeds my test cases. :)

Comment: Fair enough, no offense intended :)

Comment: The correction is, that no correction was needed. I thought, egrep or sed might depend on LC_COLLATE and include aBbCc..YyZ in A-Z (or was it bBcC...yYzZ?), but, according to my experiments, it doesn't.